# GridView. How to display current values in empty fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have GridView which filled with adapter:

```
OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter();
DataTable tableD = new DataTable();
adapter.SelectCommand = oracleCom;
adapter.Fill(tableD);
tableResults.DataSource = tableD.AsDataView();
tableResults.DataBind();
```

tableResults - it's a GridView.
I added the ability to change data in GridView:

```
tableResults.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;
tableResults.RowEditing += new GridViewEditEventHandler(tableResults_RowEditing);
tableResults.RowUpdating += new GridViewUpdateEventHandler(tableResults_RowUpdating);
tableResults.RowCancelingEdit += new GridViewCancelEditEventHandler(tableResults_RowCancelingEdit);
```

and now, from this:
[image]

when user push the Edit link he see this:
[image]

How to display current values in empty fields?

It's Addition:

```
<asp:GridView ID="tableResults" runat="server" DataMember="Table"
                EnableModelValidation="True" CssClass = "GridViewStyle" 
                OnRowDeleting = "dataViewRowDeleting" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True">
               <HeaderStyle CssClass = "GridViewHeaderStyle" />
               <RowStyle CssClass = "GridViewRowStyle"/>    
               <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text="Скачать объект" NavigateUrl='<%#"objects/" + Eval("Идентификатор") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>    
                </asp:TemplateField>
               </Columns>           
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: please show us the gridview markup too...

Comment: Are you auto-generating your columns?

Comment: Yes, autogeneratecolumns=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just click on editing but you also have to rebind your gride view
Just bind your gridview again on gridview RowEditing event like this....

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    bindGridView1();
}
```

try this, this will help you definitely. if still you faces any problem than describe here with your issue...

Comment: I did like you said but now gridview disappears when i push "Edit" link